# "Preview Version" button not visible for remote server ibm mobilefirst operations console 7.1

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobility, mobilefirst-console

We have installed the mobilefirst server on a RHEL 6.5 system. On successful deployment of the application on the server. On opening the mobilefirst operations console, we see that the "Preview Version" is not visible. We are able to see only the "Delete Version" for Android and Common resources. 
However, on running the application on localhost server, we are able to view the "Preview Version" on ibm mobilefirst console 7.1. 
Kindly help us out in understanding why the "Preview Version" is not available in the remote server version. Is there any way to obtain the "Preview Version" on the remote server operations console 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

The preview button is available only in the development environment - Studio or CLI. In a production installation the preview servlet is not available.

Comment: Please may we know the reason behind this change from the previous versions.